# How do I input n-Dimensional random numbers into a function accepting n variables

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Apologies if this is overly simple but I wasn't able to find an answer online.

### Question

Say I have a function defined as follows (and not two separate instances of random numbers),

```
f[x_,y_]:=x y
```

How can I input a set of 2 dimension random numbers into this function.
Note that I want to generate a 2 dimension random number as follows,

```
RandomReal[{min, max}, {n, 2}]]
```

The problem is that RandomReal generates a list of lists as such

```
{{x_1,y_1},{x_2,y_3},...{x_n,y_n}}
```

And I cannot input this into the function. I also wanted to repeat this a bunch of times with a Table.

This is what I tried which obviously doesn't work,

```
Table[f[RandomReal[{min, max}, {n, 2}]]],{n,1,100}]
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: There's actually a shorthand syntax for this! you're looking for `Table[f @@@ RandomReal[{min, max}, {n0, 2}], {n,1,100}]`, I think. in general `f @@@ { {a,b,c, ... }, {d,e,f, ...}, ...}` is `{f[a,b,c, ...], f[d,e,f, ...], ...}`. (assuming I'm interpreting what you want correctly, ofc)

Comment: Oh yes! That does work, thanks a lot.

Comment: You might also look into defining your function as [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html); however, thorimur's recommendation seems to be a more directly applied suggestion.